# java hibernate eclipse xml - use an entity without a primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one question that if we are creating any table in database i.e. not having any primary key(all columns values are nullable).

can't we do mapping without ID field in Hibernate O/R Mapping i.e. .hbm.xml file while working with hibernate.

The problem which i am facing is my .hbm.xml file without ID field is not getting validated.

I got the answers from u all, but i have one question that can we use transient keyword prefixed to ID variable in the entity class so that not to persist that value into database?

Comment: Is this table not related to any other table in one way or other?

Comment: As per I know no you can not create it without id cause hibernate uses the primary key as a method of keeping identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real solution is to fix your broken data model. An entity that does not have a primary key is not relational data, so you can't expect an ORM product to be able to know how to handle it.

And how Hibernate will perform update without a primary key or an uniquely identified row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in hibernate. And you shouldn't do it anyway. Databases warn you that it is not advisable not to have a primary key.

If you really don't have a set of columns that form a unique key, you have two options:

- add an auto-increment primary key (preferred)
- use raw JDBC to get the data from that particular table. You can do that with hibernate's `session.doWork(..)` method.